# Install 17.10 on 32 bit machine

Tags: system-installation, 17.10, 32-bit

The new 17.10 only has 64 bit ISOs. However 32 bit is still supported, there just are no live ISOs for it.

I have a 32 bit machine with WIFI, and I need to install from a USB disk. I tried the "mini.iso" but it doesn't have WIFI support.

What options do I have?

(PS I don't want another distro, and I can't use ethernet for installation, must be WIFI).

Comment: You have to use an older version and [release-]upgrade from there. 16.04LTS still have 32bit images  http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/

Comment: You don't want another distro, but have you tried the Ubuntu community flavours (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu)? Many of us use the flavours with lighter desktop environments in old 32-bit computers: Lubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, Ubuntu MATE, Xubuntu.

Comment: [How to go from 16.04lts to 17.10](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/upgrade-from-ubuntu-16-0417-04-to-ubuntu-17-10) instructions

Comment: @guiverc Please post that as an answer, and don't post answers as comments.

Comment: Karel's answer on a duplicate question: [How to make an Ubuntu Minimal USB using dd](https://askubuntu.com/a/1007927/301745)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install Xubuntu 32-bit. After it's installed, install the Ubuntu desktop system package:

```
sudo apt install -y ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-wallpapers ubuntu-wallpapers-artful   
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` will open up a new window allowing you to select gdm as the default login display manager. Select gdm3 and reboot.

```
sudo apt remove lightdm-gtk-greeter   
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Interesting idea! But won't it retain the xubuntu base config etc?

Comment: Also, is it not better toupgrade from a previous version of ubuntu proper, eg. 16.04lts?

Comment: In order to upgrade from 16.04 to 17.10 you would need to skip over 16.10 and 17.04 while upgrading to 17.10, which is not as good as doing a clean install of 17.10. After you have confirmed that the Ubuntu desktop system is working properly you can *optionally* uninstall the Xubuntu packages with the command: `sudo apt remove xfce4-appfinder xfce4-notifyd xfce4-panel xfce4-session xfce4-settings xfdesktop4 xfwm4 thunar thunar-volman lightdm xubuntu-artwork xubuntu-core xubuntu-default-settings`

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly, you believe that xubuntu-->17.10 is better/easier/safer/whatever than ubuntu16.04-->17.10 ? That is surprising, and I don't get it... BUT I'm a bit of a newbie!

Comment: Ubuntu only supports upgrading from one version to the next version, or from one LTS version to the next LTS version. Upgrading directly from the penultimate, or earlier, version to the current version is possible, but is liable to result in a misconfigured system. Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading/20668#20668

Comment: That makes good sense now! What I'm gonna try first [though is this approach](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/upgrade-from-ubuntu-16-0417-04-to-ubuntu-17-10) as I already downloaded it, then I'll try your approach if that doesn't work... Thanks karel! (PS the way she explains is to upgrade incrementally, which matches what you've explained here)

Comment: It may take 6+ hours in front of the computer to follow the upgrade path in the tutorial you linked to versus 30-45 minutes for a clean install of 17.10 once the 17.10 32-bit iso file has been downloaded.

Comment: LOL thanks for saving me all that time!! (However, when you say "clean install" I assume you mean the upgrade from xubuntu you explained above) I'm gonna do it your way after all...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71806/discussion-between-karel-and-grokky).