# How to install Ubuntu 17.10 32-bit

Tags: system-installation, 17.10, laptop, windows-10, 32-bit

I want to install Ubuntu 17.10 32-bit on my ASUS laptop, but when I tried to download it I got these two screens. Note that these screenshots were taken on my Windows 10 desktop. Is there any other way to install Ubuntu 17.10 32-bit?

Edit: I'm sorry everyone I should've explained myself clearer last night. The thing was, I've read the news about no 32-bit support on omgubuntu site, but it said there that you can still download it. Then I was looking for something familiar I skimmed 64-bit variants for obvious reasons and server because it was vague to me. So I checked to netboot, I saw a tree file and I was like - that's what I need, apparently I just need to download all of those files to the usb and that's it but some of them were like blanks I mean I clicked them but they weren't downloading. So I checked the installation guide - but it lead to 404 mistake so my question was how to make that netboot? Also I'm using Windows 10 on my desktop to download 17.10 to burn USB-stick that I can use to my old laptop on which it ran Windows 7 poorly so I thought of trying Ubuntu Gnome 17.10 because it's new and I wondered if it would run smoothly or not since the change of Unity. I get it that the lightest distros like Xubuntu will be more effective but I kind of dig it to the Ubuntu design. So that's it probably. 
[image]
<sup>**Ubuntu 17.10 (Artful Aardvark) Netboot**</sup>

[image]
<sup>**404 Not Found**</sup>

Comment: Note that this screenshots were taken at my Windows 10 desktop

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: how to install netboot, duh. I get it that you need to go to file tree and somehow write those to your memory stick to make it bootable but I don't know how exactly, if you know what I mean.

Comment: Please don't assume that your question is obvious.

Comment: I don't see a question - reading the graffiti on a pic is difficult "people, who still hasr a need for smth good on16R That's" makes no sense.  If you are asking for help, please be considerate of those trying to help you (make it easy for us).

Comment: What makes you think you need netboot ? Use a standard image . https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads . Download with bittorrent (or any bit torrent client). Download the server image (32 bit) , do a minimal install, boot to the command line, and then `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: @muru If it was a duplicate of that question I would have posted the same answer as my answer here under that question instead, but I couldn't do that because in that question the OP had the additional problem that his wifi didn't work when using the Ubuntu minimal CD. That makes this question a unique question relative to the other one. This question will probably get closed anyway for vandalism graffiti by the OP even though I removed it.

Comment: @karel what stops you from doing so? OP just asks "Is there any other way to install Ubuntu 17.10 32-bit?" And what's wrong with using your answer there for this one?

Comment: @muru I would like to post it there, but if I did that it could be closed there for being "not an answer" because the OP wrote in his question that he couldn't solve it that way. This is a lost question though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 17.10 ISO file is 64-bit only. The [Ubuntu 17.10 minimal CD](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso) supports installation of Ubuntu on computers that have a 32-bit processor.

#### How to make an Ubuntu Minimal USB using dd

While the minimal iso image is handy, it isn't useful for installing on UEFI-based systems that you want to run in UEFI mode. The mini iso lacks the proper files for booting the computer in UEFI mode. Thus the computer will boot in BIOS compatibility mode, and the installation will be in BIOS mode.

1. Download the Ubuntu Mini CD iso file from these links:

   - Latest current Mini ISO: https://cdimages.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mini-iso/daily-live/current/
   - Ubuntu 20.04: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/mini.iso
   - Ubuntu 18.04: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso

     Download the file called mini.iso to your Downloads folder. You can download the mini.iso file to wherever on your computer that you want, but download it to your Downloads folder so that you can easily run the commands in the following steps without changing anything.
2. Verify the md5 checksum of the Ubuntu mini CD iso file that you downloaded by running these commands:

   ```
    cd ~/Downloads/
    md5sum 'mini.iso'
   ```

   If you are using Windows Subsystem for Linux download the Microsoft File Checksum Integrity Verifier tool from the official Microsoft Download Center. The Microsoft File Checksum Integrity Verifier tool is a command line utility that computes MD5 or SHA1 cryptographic hashes for files.
3. Check that the results of the command match the MD5 checksum of the mini.iso file on the [Ubuntu Documentation Installation Minimal CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) webpage.
4. Get a USB flash drive, 1GB or larger. Delete all the files from the USB flash drive. Mount the flash drive using the *Disks* disk utility.
5. Check in the *Disks* disk utility to find out the device name of your USB flash drive. This is **very important** because if you use the wrong device name in step 6, you will overwrite your whole operating system instead of writing to the USB flash drive. So check the USB flash drive device name twice.  It should be something like `/dev/sd*` where instead of the * character there is a lower case letter like a, b, c, etc. In the following step I am assuming that the device name is `/dev/sdc`, but the device name of your USB drive could be something else like `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdb` so check the device name of your USB drive twice and make sure that you get it right in step 6!
6. Open the terminal or Windows Subsystem for Linux version 2 in Windows 10 (which you have installed) and run the following commands:

   ```
    cd ~/Downloads/  
    sudo -i  
    dd if='mini.iso' of=/dev/sdc bs=4096  ## make sure that the device name of your USB drive is correct!
   ```

   The `dd if='mini.iso' of=/dev/sdc bs=4096` command should take only a few seconds to complete on most computers because the mini.iso is a small file, less than 60MB. The result of running this command will be a bootable Ubuntu mini USB.
7. Boot the computer from the Ubuntu mini live USB. The Ubuntu mini live USB should boot successfully and show a menu screen.
8. If you select the Install option (the complete install, not the cli install) from the menu screen in Step 7, then you can select other options during the Ubuntu installation process to download all the packages that you need to perform a complete Ubuntu installation. Select the *Ubuntu desktop* package collection from the list of predefined collections of software in the Software selection screen in the Ubuntu mini CD installer. When you restart the system at the end of the installation, you will have a working Ubuntu desktop with the default desktop environment.

[image]

Comment: Karel's advice helped me, though I didn't follow it step by step. I just downloaded Ubuntu 17.10 Minimal CD, burned it to my CD and installed it on my notebook. Anyway, thank you.